# build failed in hudson when building job for deploy target

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, hudson, oracle-adf

Have built a simple ADF web application in jdevelper and built ant build file when i run the file all ant targets run fine however when i try to run targets in hudson all targets run fine except deploy  target and the build failed and  have this error

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.hudson\jobs\sunday\workspace\ViewController\build.xml:282:
>   taskdef class oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.ant.OJDeployAntTask cannot be
>   found using the classloader AntClassLoader[] total time:0 seconds
>   finished: failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build.properties file try to give absolute path for the variable oracle.home

It resolved the issue in my case.